# Композиция. Взаимное существование контейнера и композируемого объекта

Tags: ооп

Из определения композиции - "включаемый (композируемый) объект может существовать только как часть контейнера. Если контейнер будет уничтожен, то и включённый объект тоже будет уничтожен.

**Вопрос в следующем.** У нас есть класс Family в котором композируються еще три класса Husband, Wife и Child.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Может ли Family существовать с неполным набором композируемых классов или они должны быть все в обязательном порядке (например только Husband и Wife или только Wife и Child)?
- Может ли объект какого то из композируемых классов быть уничтожен до уничтожения объекта-контейнера или композируемые объекты обязаны существовать пока существует объект-контейнер? Быть создан не в момент создания объекта-контейнера а позже, например, при возникновении какого то условия?

Comment: "Композируйте" указатели, они могут быть null. Либо реализуйте паттерн [NullObject](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_(Шаблон_проектирования))

Comment: @vp_arth видите ли в чем проблема, меня не так волнует вопрос реализации, с этим я разберусь. Меня интересует как правильно с точки зрения каноничного ООП. У нас тут небольшой холивар нарисовался, я считаю что объект контейнер может существовать без композируемых объектов, а мой колега считает что нет.

Comment: каноническое ООП/Д - это не про детали реализации, а про интерфейсы и взаимодействие объектов. а вы рассуждаете именно про детали реализации.

Comment: Так я и спрашиваю про взаимодействие объектов. Может ли существовать контейнер без объектов композитов? Как именно это сделать (через указатели или нулл объект это уже второстепенное)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Может ли Family существовать с неполным набором композируемых классов
>   или они должны быть все в обязательном порядке (например только
>   Husband и Wife или только Wife и Child)?

Это зависит от логики вашей предметной области и, соответственно, кода вашего приложения. Если в приложении допускается существование неполных семей, то конечно может, а если нет то нет. Но само по себе использование композиции не накладывает никаких запретов на это.

> Может ли объект какого то из композируемых классов быть уничтожен до
>   уничтожения объекта-контейнера или композируемые объекты обязаны
>   существовать пока существует объект-контейнер? Быть создан не в момент
>   создания объекта-контейнера а позже, например, при возникновении
>   какого то условия?

Тут снова ограничения лишь в предметной области(а не в композиции). Возможно ли изменение семьи? Возможна ли смерть ее отдельных членов? Будет ли неполная семья считаться семьей в вашем приложении?

В примере с семьей уместнее использовать агрегацию а не композицию. Иначе говоря агрегируемые объекты(члены семьи) должны создаваться вне объекта агрегата(семьи). Они должны передаваться ему из вне(конструкторы, присваивание, добавления элемента в коллекцию). Соответственно они могут(и должны) существовать вне объекта агрегата. Но, еще раз повторюсь, нужно ориентироваться на предметную область и её логику.

Резюмируя: в композиции контейнер управляет жизненным циклом композируемых объектов и может создавать/не создавать/уничтожать/динамически заменять их в зависимости от своей логики. При композиции "контейнер" может существовать без содержимого а вот содержимое(члены семьи в примеры) без контейнера не могут и "умирают" вместе с ним.

Comment: Читал я эту статью. И коллега мой читал и не только ее. Возможно мой пример не совсем коректен. Тут суть в том что он (коллега) утверждает что объект контейнер обязан создаваться с композируемыми объектами, причем со всем набором, и уничтожены они могут быть только в момент уничтожения контейнера, то есть живут ровно столько сколько и он сам. Я же единственное жёсткое условие композиции вижу в том что композитные объекты принадлежат только контейнеру и при уничтожении контейнера обязаны уничтожится, но создаваться и уничтожаться до уничтожения контейнера могут по необходимости.

Comment: @torokhkun в споре с вашим коллегой вы правы. В комментарии вы довольно четко объяснили суть композиции(а по вопросу, я думал что вы до конца не понимаете). То есть контейнер управляет жизненным циклом композируемых объектов, и может создавать/не создавать/уничтожать их как угодно.

Comment: подправте ответ и я его приму

Comment: Поправил. Поправил.

Comment: @torokhkun ваш коллега не прав